# Bootstrap: Progress bars in table-condensed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

If I add a Bootstrap 3 progress bar to a Bootstrap table with table-condensed, I lose the "condensed" part of the rows (they get taller).  Is there a default minimum height to a progress bar that would force table-condensed rows to be larger?

Here's an example of the behavior I'm trying to "fix":

JSFiddle: [Condensed table/progress bar example](http://jsfiddle.net/H93tc/)

```
<table class='table table-condensed table-striped'>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table class='table table-condensed table-striped'>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>
            <div class='progress progress-striped'>
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%;">
                    Progress
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: maybe, try to override it if it does not work show some code of what is not working, you will get better anwers that way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bootstrap adds a `margin-bottom: 20px;` to its progress bar divs. Overriding that sized table rows appropriately for me.

Answer (score 7):

You need to override the margin CSS property for the progress class.

```css
.table-condensed .progress {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Add this to the head of the page as additional styles or to your css as an additional class.